# send uevent from fs/ext4 driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ext4

looking fs/ext4/super.c, I see this function

static void ext4_handle_error(struct super_block *sb)

I need have a kobj if I want to send an uevent inside ext4_handle_error function using

int kobject_uevent_env(struct kobject *kobj, enum kobject_action action, char *envp_ext[])

Question: is there a way to get *kobj from super_block *sb?

Answer (score 0):

struct ext4_sb_info *sbi = EXT4_SB(sb);  sbi->s_kobj; is this good?